# "shade is required for this module" even though shade is installed

Tags: python, ansible, openstack

Im trying to deploy an ansible playbook to spin up some new openstack instances and keep getting the errorr

```
"shade is required for this module"
```

Shade is definitely installed as are all its dependancies.

I've tried adding

```
localhost ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"
```

to the ansible hosts file as suggested here, but this did not work.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/rvqccvDLLcQ

Any advice on solving this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Playbook snipped will be helpful.

Comment: also, check that shade is installed globally or in the virtual env you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my hosts file I have the following:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python"
```

So far I haven't been using venv and my playbooks work fine.
By adding the ansible_connection= local, it should tell your playbook to be executed on the Ansible machine (I guess that's what you are trying to do).

Then when I launch a playbook, I start with the following:

```
- hosts: local
  connection: local
```

Not sure if that's the problem. If this does not work, you should give us more information (extract of your playbook at least).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing ansible using pip because I don't know why the python environment of the ansible package provided by my distro isn't the same as the shade module (installed using pip).

### On ArchLinux

```
sudo pacman -R ansible
sudo pip install ansible
```